# Prisma Schema Design User/Trainer relation?

Tags: graphql, schema, prisma

```
enum Role {
  USER
  TRAINER
  ADMIN
}

model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  role      Role     @default(USER)
  email     String   @unique
  followers User[]   @relation("FollowRelation", references: [id])
  following User[]   @relation("FollowRelation", references: [id])
  diet Diet[]
}


model Diet {
  id         Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  dietToId   Int  // confused about this part
  dietFromId Int


}
```

I am creating a personal trainer app, above are my schema defined, I am confused how can i define the schema for diet chart?

Trainer can give diet to users (both shared the same `user` schema)

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
enum Role {
  USER
  TRAINER
  ADMIN
}

model User {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  role         Role   @default(USER)
  email        String @unique
  followers    User[] @relation("FollowRelation", references: [id])
  following    User[] @relation("FollowRelation", references: [id])
  diets        Diet[] @relation("diets")
  dietsGivenBy Diet[] @relation("dietsGivenBy")
}

model Diet {
  id         Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String
  dietTo     User?  @relation("diets", fields: [dietToId], references: [id])
  dietToId   Int?
  dietFrom   User?  @relation("dietsGivenBy", fields: [dietFromId], references: [id])
  dietFromId Int?
}
```

Just like you modelled the follower/following relation, the same goes for diet where the relation will be disambiguated by the relation name.

Comment: Thank you so much, did thought of that.